# How to make input text spread on the entire grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, col

Please look at the following code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label class="col-md-4">Last Seen (Real Time)</label>
     <input class="form-control col-md-8" type="text" ng-model="status.lastSeen" ng-readonly="true"/>
</div>
```

This code creates a label and an input box. How to make the input box occupy the **entire** grid?

Comment: use `form-horizontal` http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 0):

> How to make the **input box** occupy the entire grid?

Do you want a two-dimensional text input field?

If so, rather than

```
<input type="text" />
```

You might want to use:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

instead.

**See:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a more generic solution, something that can work for other elements, not only input text.

Comment: Ah. Maybe I have misunderstood. What is it that you want to do with the input box?

Comment: I want a one-line text box. The purpose of this text box is to present information

Answer (score 0):

1. Why would you want informational (?) content to be placed in an input field?
2. The width of the input is constrained to the parent `.col-md-6`,  the class you assigned to the input (`.col-md-8`) is therefore 8/12 of the `md-6` class. Try wrapping it in its own `.form-control`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS properties to set the `height` and `width` of the `input` to `100%`?

In a `style.css` file or `<style>` element you could do the following
    input {
      height: 100%,
      width: 100%
    }

Is this the complete code? Is your code part of a `row`?

It's always good to put your `rows` and `col`s in a `container` or `container-fluid` like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="col-md-4">Last Seen (Real Time)</label>
    <input class="form-control col-md-8" type="text" ng-model="status.lastSeen" ng-readonly="true"/>
  </div>
</div>
```